# LINQ Concate Two List To make one csv list

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, csv

I have two list with different number of items like.

```
a = {"a","b","c","d","e"}<br>
b = {"f","g","h"}
```

Now I want this final output from these list.

```
a,f
b,g
c,h
d
e
```

If the list were reversed like

```
a = {"f","g","h"}
b = {"a","b","c","d","e"}
```

The result would be

```
f,a
g,b
h,c
,d
,e
```

I tried to search on internet but my search always end up on something thike this.

```
Dim lst1 As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)() From {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}<br>
Dim lst2 As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)() From {"f", "g", "h"}

Dim res = From a In lst1, b In lst2
          Select a & "," & b

For Each r In res
    Debug.Print(r)
Next
```

Showing wrong result

```
a,f
a,g
a,h
b,f
b,g
b,h
c,f
c,g
c,h
d,f
d,g
d,h
e,f
e,g
e,h
```

Comment: Please comment why negative vote.

Comment: Thanks Eser, Douglas and Matt Burland for your solutions...All three worked for me.... I tested them on more then 100,000 rows and It was done in miliseconds....I will choose Eser's solution as my answer, because it was simplest of all......Thanks again three of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More alternatives from me

```
var c = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length))
        .Select(i => (i < a.Length ? a[i] : "") + "," + (i < b.Length ? b[i] : ""))
        .ToList();
```

**Or**

```
var c = a.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
         .Concat(b.Select((s, i) => new { s, i }))
         .GroupBy(x => x.i)
         .Select(g => string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.s)))
         .ToList();
```

**To see the output:**

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, c));
```

Answer (score 2):

For the paired elements of the two lists, you can use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var a = new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
var b = new [] { "f", "g", "h" };
var c = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x + "," + y);
```

You can handle your trailing elements with some additional logic:

```
if (a.Length > b.Length)
    c = c.Concat(a.Skip(b.Length));
else if (b.Length > a.Length)
    c = c.Concat(b.Skip(a.Length).Select(y => "," + y));

foreach (string z in c)
    Console.WriteLine(z);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var a = new string[]{"a","b","c","d","e"};
var b = new string[]{"f","g","h"};

var l = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);
a = a.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat((string)null, l - a.Length)).ToArray();
b = b.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat((string)null, l - b.Length)).ToArray();

var c = a.Zip(b, (x,y) => x == null ? y : y == null ? x : x + "," + y);
```

First you pad the two arrays with nulls so they are the same length, then you `Zip` them together. Result:

```
a,f
b,g
c,h
d
e
```

In VB.Net, it would be *something* like this (can't figure out how to translate the `(string)null` part in VB):

```
dim a = {"a","b","c","d","e"}
dim b = {"f","g","h"}

dim l = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length)

a = a.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("", l - a.Length)).ToArray()
b = b.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("", l - b.Length)).ToArray()

dim c = a.Zip(b, Function(x,y) if (x = "", y, if (y = "", x , x + "," + y)))
```